# How to use filters on custom product listing?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1, theme

I need to use filters on different type of product listings not just on category page.

Let me give and example i have the product listing of mostly-viewed products . I have created a CMS page and assigned it a template file say mostly-viewd.phtml. Now i want to show filters on it.

So far i did this :

I made a custom module where,

Block/List.php

```
    <?php
    class Company_Filter_Block_List extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List
    {
        protected function _getProductCollection()
        {
        $collection = parent::_getProductCollection();

                    /* Need to work here */

        return $collection;
        }
    }
```

Now i am able to use this block and getting the product list of category i am using root category here so i am getting all the products of store now i want to filter them and show only those products , which have atleast 30 views.

Any idea how should i do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how do you show the products in the `mostly-viewd.phtml` file, is it a copy of `list.phtml` but with a certain category id or something like that?

Comment: I think it is possible using widgets. I can't comment any further because I am still learning it..

Comment: Hi Sander, yes it will be like list.phtml but the collection will be different i.e $products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')     
    ->setStoreId($storeId)
    ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
    ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'price', 'minimal_price', 'small_image')) 
    ->addViewsCount()
    ->setPageSize($productCount);

Comment: How are you specifying the products display block in the CMS page? ie, explain what you mean with 'I have created a CMS page and assigned it a template file'

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to rewrite this block.

You can just hook into `catalog_block_product_list_collection` and add your filters.